# How to solve the ng-hide flickering when page loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem with ng-hide on page loads, for the login page I used the ng-hide for displaying error massage in paragraph tag, but when the page loads I can able to see the error massage for few seconds after that it disappears. So, how to solve this flickering effect?

I also tried with ng-cloak, but it is not solved.

HTML:

```
 <p class="errred"  ng-hide="errMsg" ng-cloak >Account is suspeneded</p>
```

CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
display: none !important;
 }
```

Controller:

```
  if (response == 1)
   vm.errMsg("", null, 'This is not a registered email', null, "bgWht", 
 'Password');
    else if (response == 2) 
    //alert("acoount suuspened");
    vm.errMsg = false;
```

Comment: Did you try ng-show with negated condition? ng-hide if firing only when everithing is initialised so while it is not your message is visible.

Comment: @ Dmitry sorry I can't get you,please can you explain clearly.

Comment: <p class="errred"  ng-show="!errMsg" ng-cloak >Account is suspeneded</p> Does this work better? Otherwise it may be a problem of your errMsg not being initialised with "true" in the controller before you send your server request.

Comment: @ Dmitry I tried with it, but it is not working

Comment: Can you post some of your controller code ?

Comment: Do you set `errMsg` asynchronously? then you should try by initialising `$scope.errMsg = true` in your controller.

Comment: @ Dmitry  if (response == 1)
       vm.errMsg("", null, 'This is not a registered email', null, "bgWht", 'Password');
        else if (response == 2) 
        //alert("acoount suuspened");
        vm.errMsg = false;

Comment: Finally I solved the issue by upgrading ngAnimate.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to avoid the possibility of the text showing up then the only way is to not put it in the DOM in first place.

Let angular load up and then show put the text in there.

Below is an possible solution for you:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.errMsg = false;
  $scope.accountText = $sce.trustAsHtml(!$scope.errMsg ? 'Account is suspeneded': '');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="errMsg" /> Error Message <br/>
    <p class="errred" ng-hide="errMsg" ng-cloak >Account is suspeneded</p>
    <p class="errred" ng-bind-html="accountText"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is trustAsHtml here,getting error as trustAsHtml is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ng-if instead of ng-hide.Because when response and make scope value to true then only that div

Comment: how to give ng-if variable in above controller,I tried but it is not working,can you please help me